# Reference the content of an element in xsd

Tags: xsd

Is it possible to reference an element in xsd, so that its content is written into another?

I think of someting like "shipping address" and "billing address".
If you choose that "billing address" is the same as "shipping address", than take the content of field "shipping address" and write it into "billing address".

I'm new to xsd/xml, so suggestions and criticism are welcome.

This is what I've got so far...

```
<xsd:group name="c_Shipping_Adress">
    <xsd:element name="shipping_address">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Title"/>
                <xsd:element name="First_Name"/>
                <xsd:element name="Last_Name"/>
                <xsd:element name="Street"/>
                <xsd:element name="Zip"/>
                <xsd:element name="City"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:group>
<xsd:group name="c_Billing_Adress">
        <xsd:element name="billing_address">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice>
                    <xsd:element name="is_same_as_shipping_address">
                        <xsd:group ref="shipping_address"/>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:group name="is_not_same_as_shipping_address">
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="Title"/>
                                <xsd:element name="First_Name"/>
                                <xsd:element name="Last_Name"/>
                                <xsd:element name="Street"/>
                                <xsd:element name="Zip"/>
                                <xsd:element name="City"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:group>
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
</xsd:group>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest its not very clear what your asking, and your XSD is not structured correctly, making it difficult to determine your intentions. But hopefully the following will provide enough of a basis to build on.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid Studio 2019 BETA (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ShippingAddress" type="AddressType" />
                <xs:element name="BillingAddress" type="AddressType" />
                <xs:element name="OtherAddress">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="AddressType">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="ExtraThing" type="xs:string" />
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="AddressType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title"  type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="First_Name"  type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Last_Name" type="xs:string"  />
            <xs:element name="Street"  type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Zip"  type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"  />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```